# c# - Selenium WebDriver 4 not working with Edge (chromium)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-edgedriver

I just updated my test framework to WebDriver 4.
Seems Firefox required small tweaks, Chrome works correctly but Edge (chromium) does not work at all.
I get a following error:

Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.CapabilityType' from assembly 'WebDriver, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
I have matching Selenium.Support package installed.
Has anyone found a fix?

WebDriver 3.141.0 was working quite fine.

Answer (score 3):

The official `Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools` nuget package does not support Selenium 4+, it relies on Selenium.Webdriver 3.141.

> The Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge is a solution for developers who
> prefer to remain on Selenium 3 which is the current stable release and
> developers who have existing browser tests and want to add coverage
> for the new Microsoft Edge (Chromium) browser without changing the
> Selenium version.

> The very same Edge driver classes provided in this package are
> included in Selenium 4 and are already available today in the latest
> Selenium 4 Alpha release. If you are able to upgrade to Selenium 4
> Alpha, there is no need to use this package as Selenium should already
> have everything you need built in!

[Source](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Edge.SeleniumTools/)

Instead, I am using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver/98.0.1081-pre) community maintained Nuget package for edge and selenium 4+.

Answer (score 2):

I found a problem.
I still had microsoft.edge.seleniumTools package added and it caused some odd conflicts with the new library. After removing that It works perfectly.